# Cruise Control on a Virtual Machine

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net, continuous

Any downside to using Cruise Control on a virtual machine?

My build system is shaping up to look like

Machine 1: Source Control Repository and Server
Machine 2: Will host a virtual machine. This virtual machine will host a virtual server that will in turn host the CruiseControl.Net server.

Any apparent downside to this?

I could consolidate Machine 1 and Machine 2. I am a fan of the virtual setup for CI so that I can spawn multiple instance of spikes ( projects testing forks)

Who has experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No issues that I know of. We run CI on the Amazon VMs without problems. Setting up permissions and things like that will probably be your biggest challenge.

Answer (score 0):

None that I know of...thus far.  I've recently setup our build server on a VMWare VM and it has been behaving wonderfully thus far.  One thing I did to relax configuration was to create a domain account (we're a Windows shop) and use that domain account for all things having to do with my CruiseControl.Net VM server.  This includes using it as the identity for the CruiseControl.Net service and the dashboard web app in IIS.